# Is it proper to use HTTP response code representing business exception on server side?

Tags: web-services, exception, http-headers, http-status-codes

The background is like this:

1. The client web browser send a request to the server;
2. The server program will launch some biz check rules before doing the real work.

If check fail, some tips should be feed back to the client browser.

So, here is the question. Should I use an error response http code to indicate this, or use 200 directly, and then parse the message from response body.

Sometimes, this is not a problem. But, some client component give some util methods if error code returned. So, that's a hard decision to make:

1. return 200,and error message. parse and show them myself;
2. return some code like 500, let the client component to show it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use as many http status codes as possible. That is a standard and why should you not use them?

Here are some examples where IMHO the usage of http status codes makes sense:

- Somebody wants a dataset wich is not aviable use 404 not found
- A secured ressource needs an authentification use 401
- A ressource which is not aviable for the currient user should get a 403 forbidden
- A error accours which you cannot handle well write out an 500 status
- And so on

Look also for the logic for [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)-APIs there you can see the advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'll want to indicate the reason the service failed.  Returning custom errors can also potentially allow the client application to respond in an appropriate way.  If an input validation check fails, for instance, I imagine the user would appreciate the chance to fix and resubmit the request.  An HTTP error won't be enough to indicate what exactly went wrong.